# Cannot add more than one relationship between nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to model a social network with Neo4J. This requires a user can have multiple relationships with another user. When I try to persist these relationships, only one is stored. For example, this is the test unit I do:

```
@Test
public void testFindConnections() {

    Id id1 = new Id();
    id1.setId("first-node");

    Id id2 = new Id();
    id2.setId("second-node");
    idService.save(id2);

    id1.connectedTo(id2, "first-rel");
    id1.connectedTo(id2, "second-rel");

    idService.save(id1);

    for (Id im : idService.findAll()) {
        System.out.println("-" + im.getId());
        if (im.getConnections().size() > 0) {
            for (ConnectionType ite : im.getConnections()) {
                System.out
                        .println("--" + ite.getId() + " " + ite.getType());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This should output:

```
-first-node
--0 first-rel
--1 second-rel
-second-node
--0 first-rel
--1 second-rel
```

However, it outputs:

```
-first-node
--0 first-rel
-second-node
--0 first-rel
```

This is my node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Id {

    @GraphId
    Long nodeId;
    @Indexed(unique = false)
    String id;

    @Fetch
    @RelatedToVia(direction=Direction.BOTH)
    Collection<ConnectionType> connections = new HashSet<ConnectionType>();
}
```

And my relationship entity:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = "CONNECTED_TO")
public class ConnectionType {

    @GraphId Long id;
    @StartNode Id fromUser;
    @EndNode Id toUser;

    String type;
}
```

What could the problem be? Is there any other way to model several relationships between nodes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a shortcoming of Neo4j, it is a restriction of Spring Data Neo4j.

Usually if you have different types of relationships it would make sense to actually choose different relationship-types too, and not use a relationship-property for this.

`CONNECTED_TO` is also pretty generic.

`Id` is also a pretty generic class, shouldn't that be `User` or something similar?

`FRIEND` `COLLEAGUE` etc would be more meaningful.

---

That said, if you want to stay on your model you can either use

`template.createRelationshipBetween(entity1,entity2,type,properties,true)`

The `true` stands for allow-duplicates.

Alternatively use two different target types for the 2 types of relationships and use

`@RelatedTo(enforceTargetType=true)`

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, it is very generic, it was just a test. I wanted to do it with different types, the problem is they are defined on runtime. I found DynamicRelationshipEntity class, but not sure on how to use it, I couldn't find any example. Do you know a working example?

Comment: Use enums as rel-types. Otherwise `DynamicRelationshipType.withName(type)`.