# Duplicate relations in neo4j with spring data

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am using Neo4j 3.0.0 with spring-data-neo4j (Version 4.1.1.RELEASE) and the neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver. I want to create the same relationship (same type) between two nodes multiple times.

[image]

Persisting the `@RelationshipEntity` multiple times via a `GraphRepository` interface only creates the relationship once.

After some investigation on this topic I found the workaround described here: [Cannot add more than one relationship between nodes in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002288/cannot-add-more-than-one-relationship-between-nodes-in-neo4j) but in my version of OGM it seems the method `createRelationshipBetween` is not longer existing in the `Neo4jTemplate`.

Is there any solution available with OGM or do I have to execute the creation of the duplicate relationships with cypher queries?

I need to have the same relationship-type multiple times between two nodes, therefore to add some other reltionship-type is not an option for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SDN 4.1/Neo4j OGM [does not allow for multiple relations of the same type between two nodes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#__relationship_connecting_node_entities). The exception to the rule is when you want to maintain 2 relationships- one outgoing and one incoming- this is when you'll specify the OUTGOING and INCOMING directions.

You can have multiple relationships if you model the relationship as a relationship entity- the relationship entity must have at least one property, and the value of at least one property must differ from other relationships between the two nodes. You could consider using a timestamp as a property.

Custom Cypher can do this but there will most likely be issues when loading the entity and persisting it back to the graph with multiple relationships of the same time.